# Allowing more then one special chars in password

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords

I have regular expression which tests following rules,

1. Password must have at-least one char.
2. Password must have at-least one numeric.
3. Password must have at-least one alphanumeric char.(More then one should be allowed)

**My attempt is this,**

```
/^([a-zA-Z+]+[0-9+]+[!@#$%^&*])$/
```

This works fine as for most cases except if I add more then one alpha-numeric chars.

***Tests***

- Test [qwer1234] Result [**Not Valid**] Conclusion [**Passed**]
- Test [qwer1234$] Result [**Valid**] Conclusion [**Passed**]
- Test [qwer1234#$] Result [**Not Valid**] Conclusion [**Failed**]

The last test should get Passed but it fails. I know where things are wrong but couldn't get hang of the regex magic. My thoughts about what is wrong is,

```
[0-9+] // This + sign shows that you can have more then 1 of that range of numerics
```

Where,

```
[!@#$%^&*] // Does not have the + sign
```

I tried,

```
[!@#$%^&*+] // Does not have the + sign
[!@#$%^&*]+ // Does not have the + sign
```

Both didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there any *legitimate* reason you have to cram all this into one regex?

Comment: I'm confused on your explanation. Do the parts of the password have to come in the order you specified? Like, does it have to be (alpha characters)(numbers)(special characters), or can it be any mix of at least 1 of each? I'm also confused why you have the `+` inside of the `[ ]`...

Comment: If they have to be in that order, then you should use: `/^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[!@#$%^&*]+)$/`. Putting the `+` outside of the `[ ]` means match at least 1 of the chars in the set. So the very least you can have something like `a2&`. Putting `+` inside of the `[ ]` means to match the `+` character. So technically, you could've had the password `++*` in your regex and it would pass. I'm thinking it shouldn't though...

Comment: If you don't need order, try something like: `/(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^!@#$%^&*]*[!@#$%^&*])/` which just requires at least 1 of each in the password. http://jsfiddle.net/bJTTk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you actually need, from your confusing description of your situation, here are two regexes that I hope help. This first one requires that the password start with at least 1 Alphabetic character, have at least 1 Numeric character second, then at least 1 Special character last.

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[!@#$%^&*]+)$/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ECwP8/

If you don't require the characters to come in a specific order, you can try this regex:

```
/(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^!@#$%^&*]*[!@#$%^&*])/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bJTTk/1/

This one simply requires that there be at least 1 Alphabetic character, at least 1 Numeric character, and at least 1 Special character, occur in the password in any order.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to mash it all into one regex?

```
function test_password(password) {
    if (password.length < 2) return false;            // Minimum length
    if (!/[0-9]/g.test(password)) return false;       // Needs a number
    if (!/[a-z]/gi.test(password)) return false;      // Needs a letter
    if (!/[^a-z0-9]/gi.test(password)) return false;  // Needs a special char

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It will work if a characters should be first, numerics should be second and alpahanumerics should be next.

/^[a-zA-Z]+[1-9]+[!@#$%^&*]+$/